# Animation in canvas in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i move this line vertically animation wise in canvas

```
ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle= "yellow";
ctx.fillRect(30,30,1,100);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
```

I am asking because I am trying to make a laser in a game I am creating.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a timer like [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) or use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). Generally when you want to control the frame-rate a simple timer will do. Doing this allows you to have frames, in which then on each frame you update your object's position.

For moving an object have it's `x` and `y` position be variables, then have a variable for moving in a direction, such as `moveY` or `velY`. You would update your positions by your intended movements each frame. This is done by clearing the canvas then redrawing your object at its new position.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var xPos = 30;
var yPos = 30
var moveY = 10;
var delay = 100;

var timer = setInterval(function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);    
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle= "yellow";
    ctx.fillRect(xPos,yPos,1,100);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
    yPos += moveY;
}, delay);
```

```css
canvas{ border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=500>
```

Comment: you can also use setTimeout within a loop so that it waits for the function to finish first before executing the next one.

    function foo() {
    
     setTimeout(foo, delay);
   }

Comment: how does var timer look like as a function? and not a variable

Comment: @Demoman09 `timer` is a variable that has the interval id, it can be used to clear the timer so it doesn't run indefinitely. It is indeed a variable, it's just that the method `setInterval` accepts a `function` as the first parameter.

Comment: @PauAI That is another way to do it, I just mentioned `setInterval` because it tends to be more intuitive. Although because JavaScript is synchronous the function will never start running before the previous call is finished (*unless the code inside is ajax*).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek yo can we chat again?

Comment: @Demoman09 Sure. *Note* if this post answered your original question you can give it a check-mark as *accepted*, and other questions would be better off as a new post.

Comment: hey @SpencerWieczorek remember me?